# How do I get to the other side of this bridge?

Tags: dark-souls-3

If you've been to the Undead settlement then you already know this. In the Undead Settlement at the Foot of the High Wall, there's a place with a bunch of dead pilgrims, except for that one sorcerer guy. Anyway, if you peer over the edge you can see a broken bridge that has a dead dragon and a few loot gleams. I was wondering how to get over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bridge is accessible from Farron Keep. This is location where you fight mini boss:

> Stray Demon

It's not hard to find: in swamp area look for huge ladder, climb it, there will be room with bonfire, use elevator next to it, then search for a gap in railing.

On this map ladder is marked as B, I put map as spoiler just in case:

> [image]

[This walkhthrough video](https://youtu.be/QTHovXsM6OU?t=833) can show exact path.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been trying to figure this out forever.

Comment: @KerikoKraft if this answers your question, you can select this answer as correct one using checkmark to the left next to vote arrows!